# Avoiding url to add current url

Tags: php, html, url, anchor

I am printing my custom URL's in footer which I am getting from database, Some thing like this Assume this contains **www.google.com** link.

```
 <li><a href="<?php echo $links['link_url']?>"><?php echo $links['title'] ?></a></li>
```

When I click on this link at footer, it redirecting with my current page URL

> **www.mydomainname.com/www.google.com**

How can I avoid attaching my current domain name to it? It should be redirect to **"www.google.com"**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `href` attribute specifies the URL of the page you're linking to. If you don't provide a protocol to the URL it will assume it's a relative URL and therefore append it to your current path / URL. If you specify a protocol (such as `http://` or `https://`) you'll be taking to the absolute URL. You want to link to use absolute URLs and not relative ones.

Add website url with protocol in your database.

e.g. http://www.google.com

So,it will redirect to google page.